# weak convergence in compact space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $f \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$. I need to show, that $f_n \rightarrow f$ weakly if and only if $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||f_n||<\infty$ and $f_n(t) \rightarrow f(t)$ for all $t \in X.$ I'm familiar with weakly convergence, but I don't understan how to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In case of $C[0,1]$ weak convergence means (so called Riesz representation theorem) that for any measure $u$ on $[0,1]$ we have $\int_0^1 f_n(t)du(t)$ converges to $\int_0^1f(t)du(t)$. Then take for $u$ atomic measure with single atom at $t$ to get conclusion. By the way, in your post X =[0,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $f_n\to f$ weakly. For $t\in[0,1]$, consider the point measure $\delta_t$. Then
$$
f_n(t)=\int_{[0,1]} f_n\,d\delta_t\to\int_{[0,1]}f\,\delta_t=f(t). 
$$
The fact that $\|f_n\|<c$ for some $c$ is the usual result (using the Uniform Boundedness Principle) that weakly convergent sequences in a Banach space are bounded.

Conversely, if $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $\|f_n\|<c$ for all $n$, then for any measure $\mu$ we have $$\int_{[0,1]}f_n\,d\mu\to\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\mu$$ by Dominated Convergence.